# RestKit and XCode4 Error

Tags: xcode, restkit

I'm trying to use RestKit in an XCode4 project, but it's giving me this warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kagi/Coding/iOS/Projects/testProject/RestKit/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
```

I'm not seeing anything in my build settings that points to that directory...

Any insight is always appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try to check with this method of adding RestKit via this [tutorial](http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/)

Comment: If you still have the issue check the below link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534370/1101962

Comment: The stackoverflow link from Nakkeeran (above) seems to be good, though I've not tried it out. The tutorial referenced by tegbains (above) appears to be out-of-date, in that it contains broken links. https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I looked at the RKTwitterCoreData example application which is supplied with RestKit.

In its build settings it **doesn't** set a value for the "Library Search Paths" (contrary to the RestKit instructions on github). I removed this setting from my project and it now works.

Comment: I don't have anything in "Library Search Paths" in RestKit project but it still show the error `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/myname/Projects/../Project/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator'`